# How can I fix "sqlite3 has text relocations" warning in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I required to have sqlite3 in my Nexus 5, so I installed SQLite Installer for root from the market, I looked like it did not work, so I decided to do it manually, I pasted the sqlite3 file in system/xbin and gave permissions, It works fine, however, I always get this error:

```
Warning: linker: sqlite3 has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
```

I'd like to fix it, but there's no information on the web about it,could you help me out please? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be a result of two ndk-gcc bugs mentioned at
 https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23203

and stated there to have been fixed as of ndk-r8c.

It would appear that the check for libraries with the issue has been added only recently.

Comment: So, installing android-ndk-r9c-windows-x86_64.zip (in my case) would solve the issue? I thought the problem was with the actual phone, thanks for the help!

Comment: I was reading about that, it's like a SDK to include parts of the apps in other languages such as C++ and C, but, what's the relation between that package and the error that I'm getting when running sqlite3 from my phone? thanks!